# Using json encode in php array with cURL

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am very much a noob...so please go easy :)

I need to replicate this json using a php json encode:

```
{
  "payment": {
    "amount": 10.00,
    "memo": "Client x paid with $10.00 of nickles"
  }
}
```

Here is what I am doing, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it has to do with the "payment" key possibly not being represented somehow in the following code?

```
    $params = array(
                      'payment'     => "",
                      'amount'      => $paymentAmount,
                      'memo'        => $memo
                    );

    $content = json_encode($params);

    // send to chargify
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $params = array(
             'payment'=> array(
                           'amount'   => $paymentAmount,
                           'memo'    => $memo
                          ),
            );
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been beating my head against the wall for an hour. Knew it was something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you know what you want the JSON to look like but don't know how to build the PHP array, just use `json_decode` on the well-formed JSON and examine the result:

```
$json = '{
          "payment": {
              "amount": 10.00,
              "memo": "Client x paid with $10.00 of nickles"
              }
        }';
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
[
    'payment' => 
    [
        'amount' => 10,
        'memo' => 'Client x paid with $10.00 of nickles',
    ],
]
```

Examining the output tells you how to build the array.

The same basic idea can be applied in the reverse direction if you know the array shape you need, but you're not sure what the JSON should look like.  Just `json_encode` the good array and examine the results.